# New text overwrites the old in ShareLaTeX / Overleaf

Tags: overleaf, sharelatex, keyboard

I'm editing a question by someone who was very new to using LaTeX and have a question to which I and they haven't been able to find the answer by Google. When we want to edit/write new text in `ShareLaTeX`, it overwrites the old text that is already there. When we want to correct a sentence for example, what we write overwrites the old text letter-by-letter.

I'm now having the same problem in Overleaf, and I am not at all new to latex, or unix, or Apple (I'm on a mac.) There isn't a key that says "insert" on a mac keyboard.

Is there a way to avoid this? It suddenly happened while editing my document. Presumably it's because of some random combination of things I typed, accidentally (I type fast) is there a quick way to undo it? Power cycling my keyboard hasn't helped. Restarting the editor in a new tab fixes it but isn't very elegant – I'm editing a book so that's a big compile for no reason.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you tell what editor you're using for typing your documents?

Comment: You have probably pressed the insert/replace key by accident. Try pressing it again.

Comment: I use shareLaTex :) What key is the insert/replace key?

Comment: The one which says "insert" or the analog command in your language.

Comment: This is really awkard, but it worked just closing the editor and restarting... Thank you for your answers, sorry for the stupid question!